# echo -e: A white space is added before the second sentence in <first sentence> \n <second sentence>

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron, pipe

In Bash, I'm having a small trouble with the `echo` command and one of its `-e` sequences: A white space is added before the second sentence in `<first sentence> \n <second sentence>`.

---

This is my command:

```
echo -e "0 0 * * * ~/cronDaily.sh \n 0 0 * * 0 ~/cronWeekly.sh" | crontab
```

This is my current state (what's being printed into crontab):

```
0 0 * * * ~/cronDaily.sh
 0 0 * * 0 ~/cronWeekly.sh
```

This is the desired state in crontab:

```
0 0 * * * ~/cronDaily.sh
0 0 * * 0 ~/cronWeekly.sh
```

---

What can be done against the empty space added after /n after execution?

Edit: I was thinking about removing the space right after `\n` but it makes the code less comfortable to read and I would prefer a solution that let's me keep it, maybe some negation combo, some placeholder that will come after `\n` but negate the space after it from being printed (and maybe also before it, if there is one).

Comment: @userunknown It is reopened, you may add your answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the space after the `\n` (line break escape character):

```bsh
echo -e "0 0 * * * ~/cronDaily.sh \n0 0 * * 0 ~/cronWeekly.sh" | crontab

#                                  /\
#                                 here
```

To please your aesthetics, you can also split it up into two `echo`s:

```bsh
{ echo "0 0 * * * ~/cronDaily.sh" ; echo "0 0 * * 0 ~/cronWeekly.sh" ; } | crontab
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo -e "0 0 * * * ~/cronDaily.sh  
0 0 * * 0 ~/cronWeekly.sh" | crontab
```

will do the job. An opening quote allows you to insert linebreaks. Of course Byte Commanders answer is right, and you have to make a tradeoff between readability and orientation on shell syntax.

Syntax colorizing editors might help making the source more readable and higlight special characters like '\n', which would improve Byte Commanders solution even more. But do you have control over what the user of the code will use?